# error "Sequence contains no elements"

Tags: c#, linq

i have used below linq query code but it returns "Sequence contains no elements" , i am sure there is one item that should be return.

the code is like below:

```
tblDocTranstoCon doctranstocon =_DataContext.tblDocTranstoCons
                       .Single(dtcon => (dtcon.Docid == _DocID)
                                     && (dtcon.Transid==e.TransmittoconID)
                                     && (dtcon.Transid==e.TransID));
```

Comment: Any chance you have the comparisons wrong?  You're comparing `dtcon.Transid` to both `e.TransmittoconID` and `e.TransID` - I'm guessing the second one is right, but perhaps the first one is referring to the wrong field on `dtcon`?

Comment: why condition( dtcon.Transid ==) is two times?

Comment: thanks it seems problem is "why condition( dtcon.Transid ==) is two times?"

Answer (score 2):

You should use `SingleOrDefault` if there is no item returned.

```
tblDocTranstoCon doctranstocon =_DataContext.tblDocTranstoCons
   .SingleOrDefault(dtcon => (dtcon.Docid == _DocID)
                   && (dtcon.Transid == e.TransmittoconID)
                   && (dtcon.Transid == e.TransID));
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem replace the method Single() call with SingleOrDefault() method. The method SingleOrDefault() returns a null value if there are no source records that matches to the filtering criteria. see [here](http://www.techdreams.org/microsoft/aspnet/fixing-linq-error-sequence-contains-no-elements-c-linq/368-20080925)